# Не получается сделать сниппет CRC в VSCode, который берет название текущего каталога

Tags: visual-studio-code

Пытаюсь создать свой сниппет, который при вводе crc создаст структуру подобной:

```js
function *название_папки*()
{
  return ;
}

export default *название_папки*;
```

Мои попытки:

```json
{
    "Create react component": {
        "prefix": "crc",
        "body": [
            "function ${${TM_DIRECTORY/.*\\(.*)$/$1/}}()",
            "{",
            "\treturn ;",
            "}",
            "",
            "export default ${1:};"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается чтобы поставить один обратный слэш, нужно указать его как `\\\\`.

```json
{
    "Create react component": {
        "prefix": "crc",
        "body": [
            "function ${1:${TM_DIRECTORY/^.+\\\\(.*)$/$1/}}()",
            "{",
            "\treturn ;",
            "}",
            "",
            "export default ${1:};"
        ]
    }
}
```